# Named pipe accessible to everyone

Tags: c#, windows, security, winapi, acl

I want to create a NamedPipe thats accessible by "Everyone" across computers in network.

Here are two types of code that I tried, non worked:

```
 NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer; 
        try
        {
            PipeSecurity pipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();
            pipeSecurity.SetAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));

            pipeServer =
                new NamedPipeServerStream(
                    "Win7-PC\\testpipe",
                    PipeDirection.InOut,
                    NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances,
                    PipeTransmissionMode.Message,
                    PipeOptions.Asynchronous,
                    4096,
                    4096,
                    pipeSecurity, System.IO.HandleInheritability.None);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("ERRRRRR");

            throw;
        }
```

Second method:

```
NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer; 
        try
        {
            PipeSecurity pipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();
            // allow network access, allow read/write to everyone locally and the owner/creator
            pipeSecurity.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm("D:(A;;FA;;;NU)(A;;0x12019f;;;WD)(A;;0x12019f;;;CO)");

             pipeServer =
                new NamedPipeServerStream(
                    "testpipe",
                    PipeDirection.InOut,
                    NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances,
                    PipeTransmissionMode.Message,
                    PipeOptions.Asynchronous,
                    4096,
                    4096,
                    pipeSecurity);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("ERRRRRR");

            throw;
        }
```

One throws access denied (first method) during server initialization, 2nd method server starts but doesn't let anyone to connect to it.

Please advise

Comment: Hi GMX, I test your first method on my Windows 10 PC, it works for me. Do you use Windows 7? Which .NET Framework version do you target?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Its Windows 7 and I don't have specific .NET framework requirement. Anything works

Comment: I even went C++ route, exact same result. Also I ran the code in Windows 8.1, again, same result, access denied.

Comment: try give all access to *Anonymous Logon* - add `(A;;GA;;;AN)` - say use `D:P(A;;GA;;;AN)(A;;GA;;;WD)` for test

Comment: @RbMm Server started, but when I tried to connect to it from another PC, I get "invalid username/password"

Comment: but how this related to dacl ?